# How do I separate these apparently linked columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

Running into something strange as I try to use dplyr's select command to reduce the number of columns I have. I name three columns but I keep getting 4. Aside from the star trek chain of command flashbacks I find this behaviour odd and not sure how to get around it. Also, why is this happening?

Here is my dataframe expressing the number of occurrences at in each block of time in a day. It's also pretty verbose for just 6 rows of data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test <- structure(list(Day = c("Dec 10", "Dec 10", "Dec 10", "Dec 10", 
"Dec 11", "Dec 11"), Number = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L), 
    time = c("08:30", "12:00", "15:30", "19:00", "08:30", "12:00"
    ), Start = structure(c(1544430600, 1544443200, 1544455800, 
    1544468400, 1544517000, 1544529600), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), n = c(29L, 74L, 20L, 26L, 29L, 
    32L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), vars = c("Day", "Number", "time"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(Day = c("Dec 10", 
"Dec 10", "Dec 10", "Dec 10", "Dec 11", "Dec 11"), Number = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L), time = c("08:30", "12:00", "15:30", 
"19:00", "08:30", "12:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), vars = c("Day", "Number", "time"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
    26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
    38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
    50L, 51L, 52L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    Day = c("Dec 10", "Dec 10", "Dec 10", "Dec 10", "Dec 11", 
    "Dec 11", "Dec 11", "Dec 11", "Dec 12", "Dec 12", "Dec 12", 
    "Dec 12", "Dec 13", "Dec 13", "Dec 13", "Dec 13", "Dec 14", 
    "Dec 14", "Dec 14", "Dec 14", "Dec 15", "Dec 15", "Dec 15", 
    "Dec 17", "Dec 17", "Dec 17", "Dec 17", "Dec 18", "Dec 18", 
    "Dec 18", "Dec 18", "Dec 19", "Dec 19", "Dec 19", "Dec 4", 
    "Dec 4", "Dec 4", "Dec 4", "Dec 5", "Dec 5", "Dec 5", "Dec 5", 
    "Dec 6", "Dec 6", "Dec 6", "Dec 6", "Dec 7", "Dec 7", "Dec 7", 
    "Dec 7", "Dec 8", "Dec 8", "Dec 8"), Number = c(10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
    17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L), 
    time = c("08:30", "12:00", "15:30", "19:00", "08:30", "12:00", 
    "15:30", "19:00", "08:30", "12:00", "15:30", "19:00", "08:30", 
    "12:00", "15:30", "19:00", "08:30", "12:00", "15:30", "19:00", 
    "08:30", "12:00", "15:30", "08:30", "12:00", "15:30", "19:00", 
    "08:30", "12:00", "15:30", "19:00", "08:30", "12:00", "15:30", 
    "08:30", "12:00", "15:30", "19:00", "08:30", "12:00", "15:30", 
    "19:00", "08:30", "12:00", "15:30", "19:00", "08:30", "12:00", 
    "15:30", "19:00", "08:30", "12:00", "15:30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-53L), vars = c("Day", "Number", "time"), drop = TRUE)))
```

You can see in the output that there's only 3 variables listed but oddly shows more. And when I select for specific variables or subtract others it won't work.

```
test %>% 
  select(Day, time, n)
```

Comment: What is your output? I get four columns: `Number Day time n`

Comment: Please also mention the libraries used (dplyr, tidyr).

Comment: That is my output as well @Nakx. No matter how I filter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511743/adding-missing-grouping-variables-message-in-dplyr-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tibble should be ungrouped before selecting variables, as described here ["Adding missing grouping variables" message in dplyr in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511743/adding-missing-grouping-variables-message-in-dplyr-in-r):

Without ungrouping:

```
test %>% 
  select(Day, time, n)

> test %>% 
+   select(Day, time, n)
Adding missing grouping variables: `Number`
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Day, Number, time [6]
  Number Day    time      n
   <int> <chr>  <chr> <int>
1     10 Dec 10 08:30    29
2     10 Dec 10 12:00    74
3     10 Dec 10 15:30    20
4     10 Dec 10 19:00    26
5     11 Dec 11 08:30    29
6     11 Dec 11 12:00    32
```

With ungrouping

```
test %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Day, time, n)

> test %>% 
+   ungroup() %>%
+   select(Day, time, n)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Day    time      n
  <chr>  <chr> <int>
1 Dec 10 08:30    29
2 Dec 10 12:00    74
3 Dec 10 15:30    20
4 Dec 10 19:00    26
5 Dec 11 08:30    29
6 Dec 11 12:00    32
```

Answer (score 0):

Ungrouping the dataframe fixes it all.