# ungrouping doesn't resolve "Adding missing grouping variables"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I have a data frame and as always I am doing some calculation on it. The dataframe is so long and I am just showing an example of portion of it below:

```
                 ID     ID2      Date       yq       flag
                <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <date>     <chr>                  
 1            1012960 023-461~ 2011-06-28  2011      0
 2            1012960 023-461~ 2011-06-28  2011      0
 3            1012960 003-388~ 2015-01-28  2015      0
 4                   ..............................
 5                   ..............................
```

What I am trying to do is grouping by "yq" and "flag" and then count the total number of values in each "yq" and for each "flag". I used the code below:

```
temp <- new_df_V %>% count(yq, flag)
```

This However, will result in a table in this form:

```
                        <dbl> <yearqtr> <dbl> <int>
 1                    1012960 2011        0     1
 2                    1012960 2011        1     1
 3                    1013515 2014        0     2
 4                    1013515 2016        0     1
```

and a warning message saying that "**Adding missing grouping variables: `ID`**". Definately this is not the result I want and I am not sure why the ID column is added to the result. I checked this link:["Adding missing grouping variables" message in dplyr in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511743/adding-missing-grouping-variables-message-in-dplyr-in-r) and used "ungroup" function to fix it but even after **ungrouping** the result is the same and I get the same warning.
Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe `temp <- new_df_V %>% ungroup() %>% count(yq, flag)`

Comment: Thanks @Duck. It worked. For my reference, what's the reason that ungrouping first (`ungroup(ID)`) and then `temp <- new_df_V %>% count(yq, flag)` doesn't work?

Comment: It might be because the function `ungroup()` was not properly applied. Next time, do the ungroup before any computing ;)